# Block element disappears after horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css

I have code similar to this situation:

```css
table {
  table-layout: auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1 solid black;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="tabs">
    smth
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill31222222</td>
        <td>Smith12333333333333</td>
        <td>5031231231231232</td>
        <td>Jill31231231231</td>
        <td>Smith312312312312</td>
        <td>50312312312312312</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve12312312312</td>
        <td>Jackson1233123123123123312</td>
        <td>94312312312312</td>
        <td>Jill312312312312</td>
        <td>Smith312312312</td>
        <td>5031233123123123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a table with `table-layot: auto` style, which cells display very large text. Above table are displayed tabs. After horizontal scrolling `tabs div` is cut.
Is there a possibility to stretch `tabs` div, depending on table's width?

Relevant image:

[image: Cut block]

Comment: You mean that the div saying "smth" is only as wide as the body?

Comment: Use [table responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive).

Comment: @MrLister yes, it's width corresponds to the width in the initial state of the  horizontal-scroll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A div (or any element with `display:block`) is only as wide as its container.
So one solution is to put it in a container that is as wide as the table. For instance, an `inline-block` around the table, which will stretch itself to the correct width.

```css
.div-and-table-wrapper {
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:100%;
}

table {
  table-layout: auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1 solid black;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-and-table-wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    smth
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>

        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill31222222</td>
        <td>Smith12333333333333</td>
        <td>5031231231231232</td>
        <td>Jill31231231231</td>
        <td>Smith312312312312</td>
        <td>50312312312312312</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve12312312312</td>
        <td>Jackson1233123123123123312</td>
        <td>94312312312312</td>
        <td>Jill312312312312</td>
        <td>Smith312312312</td>
        <td>5031233123123123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: the `min-width` is in there to ensure that the tabs div will be at least as wide as the window in case the table is narrower.
If you don't want that, i.e. if you want the tabs div to always be the same width as the table, perhaps you're better off turning it into a `caption`.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width of the parent `div` to `fit-content`:

```css
table {
  table-layout: auto;
  background-color: tomato;
  border: 1 solid black;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabs {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}

.tabs-wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <div class="tabs">
    smth
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Sample</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jill31222222</td>
        <td>Smith12333333333333</td>
        <td>5031231231231232</td>
        <td>Jill31231231231</td>
        <td>Smith312312312312</td>
        <td>50312312312312312</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Eve12312312312</td>
        <td>Jackson1233123123123123312</td>
        <td>94312312312312</td>
        <td>Jill312312312312</td>
        <td>Smith312312312</td>
        <td>5031233123123123</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

An alternative would be, as Mr Lister already suggested, using `inline-block` instead of `fit-content`.